# Group variables seeing the class

Tags: data-imputation

I need to perform a classification model (logistic regression, pnn or neural network).

I'm doing the part of data preparation in R. I have a nominal variable, that has more than 800 levels. I need to group it, so I though of using a decision tree to do it. At that moment, I was sure I could use the target variable as a predictor for the variable I need to impute.

The thing is that now, I'm not sure if that's ok, because, even if I only let it see the class in training, it will group it considering the target, so when I train a model like a logistic regression, this variable will be chosen.

I thought of making a partition to do this kind of binning and then exclude this data  from training and testing to perform the final models (but my dataset is very small, so I will do this unless I have another choise).

The question is, should I let the variable see the class to group it or should I use the other variables and perform for example knn to classify it? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Some would argue that this would artificially decrease variability in your data (hence the not-so-useful predictor may be chosen) and it is thus better to introduce a random error into any conditional imputation. In any case, best to run both models and see how it affects the results. Check this for further disucssion http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/312-2012.pdf